# How to use Barby::Code128A on Heroku server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, barcode

I can`t figure out why on heroku server my app crashed. On local server all seems works.

```
2012-08-01T17:14:50+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant Barby::Code128A):
2012-08-01T17:14:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/order.rb:102:in `generate_shipment'
2012-08-01T17:14:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/order.rb:60:in `generate_items'
2012-08-01T17:14:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

I tried to add Procfile, but it not helps me either. 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile/#deploying-to-heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to require the code128a generator seperately before using. Just add the following line to the file where you are using `Barby::Code128A`

```
require 'barby/barcode/code_128'
```